# Cannot Backup and Restore using SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server, cmd, sqlcmd

I'm trying to restore a database from a backup.

The **BACKUP** sqlcmd I'm using is the following

```
sqlcmd -e -s [SERVERNAME] -q "backup database [DATABASE_NAME] to disk ='[BackupLocation]'"
```

For the **RESTORE**, I'm using the following sqlcmd for restore.

```
sqlcmd -e -s [SERVERNAME] -q "restore database [DATABASENAME] from disk ='[BackUpLocation]"
```

When i try to **restore** the database I get this error.

> Msg 3159, Level 16, State 1. Server [SERVERNAME], Line 1
>   The Tail of the log for the database "[DATABASE_NAME]" has note been backed up. Use BACKUP
>   LOG WITH NO RECOVERY or WITH STOPAT clause of the RESTORE statement to just overwrite the contents of the log.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server [SERVERNAME], Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I'm trying to incorporate the tail log backup but I can't seem to find a way, I keep getting errors like the one below. I already added WITH NORECOVERY at the end of the backup sqlcmd, but had no luck.

> Msg 3032, Level 16, State 2, Server [SERVERNAME], Line 1
>   One or more of the options  are not supported for this statement. Review the documentation for supported options.

Does anyone know how can I accomplish this task? Backing up and restoring successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to backup the log with norecovery to get a tail log backup. So, `backup log [yourDatabase] to disk='your log file' with norecovery`. Alternatively, if you're just playing around (or are legitimately replacing your database, just add `with replace` to the restore command.